# How can I have a menu appear over an image after it is hovered on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a portfolio page that will have images of different things I've worked on. When I hover on an image I would like for it to gray out (as if there was a div overlapping it with 0.4 opacity) and for a few buttons (view source, view demo) to pop up over the image.

I want to lay these "portfolio items" in three bootstrap columns. I looked at overlapping a div on top of it that would be hidden until hover using a z-index but I can't figure out how to position it while also using bootstrap to keep it responsive.

Here is what I have so far. Is there another easier way to do this?

```
<div id="portfolio-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <h2 class="center-text">My Portfolio</h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" id="portfolio-items">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <img src="includes/img/headers.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a little CSS to do this.

I've set the opacity of `.portfolio_text` to 0 but I set it to 1 when you hover over its parent `.portfolio`. I've also added a transition so it fades as opposed to just popping in.

```css
.portfolio {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}

.portfolio img,
.portfolio_text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.portfolio_text {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1)
}

.portfolio:hover .portfolio_text {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <img src="http://silayexportinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/placeholder-3.jpg" />
  <div class="portfolio_text">
    <span>Look at my Buttons</span>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```